# transaction from tableview cell to logout

Tags: ios, uitableview, logout

i have login/register screen in ios mobile app, this written in ViewController view. i have left side menu as `UITableview` , i want assign logout from current user (using parse) when i press logout in menu. i use this code to transaction from left side menu to login/register after make logout to current user and stop update location in mapkit by using :

```
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

let centerViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
let centerNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)
let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = centerNavController
appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggle(MMDrawerSide.left, animated: true, completion: nil)
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
PFUser.logOut()
```

i have got error when i clock on logout as this :

[error screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23tOb.png)

where is the wrong please ?

Comment: I would suspect that `PFUser.current` is trying to read the `currentUser` instance after it was deallocated. Have you called `logOut` before the creating this query? If all you need is the `objectId` try capturing that as a string value before calling `logOut` so you don't need to call `PFUser.current` in what seems like a race condition.

Comment: yes i create user and login it to detect his location , in this moment i want to click on logout in side menu to logout this current user and transaction me to login screen again. this what i need .